How can I add a toggle to switch on and off the display of my class?
I have problems integrating a .toggle to switch on and off my display for my class. Is it maybe something else ?
I tried to include .toggle in my line, but it doesnt seem to work, and mdn does not answer that question. And instead of showing my nav normally, when I clicked on my div with the addEventListener, it didn't even showed up.
const burgerMenu = document.querySelector('.burger-menu-mobile')
    
const navigationBar = document.querySelector('.nav-bar')
    
burgerMenu.addEventListener('click', function(e){
    navigationBar.style.display = "block"
    console.log("working")
})

Where do I add toggle or something that does the job ?
